# How to skip created_at from update with updateOrInsert

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, whmcs

i dont want to update `created_at` every time, but want to update only `updated_at`. so how can i use it.

My code is:

```
Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::table('whois_database_old')
->updateOrInsert(
    ['year' => $year, 'month' => $month],
    ['data_count' => $count, 'file_name' => $zip_file_name, 'size' => $size, 'status' => '0', 'hash' => $hash, 'path' => $path, 'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()]
);
```

Comment: Just remove `'created_at' => Carbon::now()` And in mysql please set `created_at` to `current_timestamp` as default

Comment: @IndraKumarS Yes correct suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Better Solution is to create model for `whois_database_old` table for example if your model is `WhoIs` then you can call like this

```
WhoIS::updateOrCreate( ['year' => $year, 'month' => $month],
    ['data_count' => $count, 'file_name' => $zip_file_name, 'size' => $size, 'status' => '0', 'hash' => $hash, 'path' => $path)
```

So no need to manually pass `updated_at` .Since model will take care of updating `updated_at` time .